# Webpack SSR Node.js module.export is not exported anything

Tags: node.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am trying to integrate react ssr to existing nodejs express application. I still do not want to make the whole application to webpack, I am trying to make only a path to render the react code.

src/index.js

```
export const ssrHandler = (req, res) => {
    // some react code here.
}
```

webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all rules here.
    ]
  },
};
```

I am building using following command `webpack --config webpack/server.config.js`

I am trying to import the bundled file in another nodejs express code like following

api/server.js

```
// nodejs code here

const ssr = require('../dist/server-bundle');
app.use('/path', ssr.ssrHandler);
```

But whatever configuration I tried, `ssr` is always an empty object '{}', is there a way to make the bundle export a function, I checked generated code, there are no module.export in the generated file.

Thanks in advance. Please point to other similar questions if found any, I am really tired of searching for this similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the some more [output](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) configuration is needed in order to make this work:

```
  output: {
    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  },
```

And also:

```
const ssrHandler = (req, res) => {

};

export default ssrHandler;
```

I wish I could provide some more insight - but this is just the result of an [issue search](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2030#issuecomment-433189477)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` option worked for me, I don't like default export anyway.